# Adding wordpress web template with different styles and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have to make a new homepage on a wordpress website and the new homepage must be with different css and javascript than the css and js of the theme. I have created a page template with the new layout but I found it difficult to include the styles and js and I have started to wandering if this is the wright way. What I have done is to create a new page template with everything in it with a separate head tag where i will include the styles, but I couldn`t find out how to set the path to the files properly. I have to add bootstrap css as well and 4 js files and the new files should not affect the other pages of the website.

Also I have to add a slider on which should be a text which have to be editable from the administration panel. Do I have to make it with a plugin because I was given html and css files and the slider is made with javascript, and I have to use those files.

Can anyone give an advice which is the wright way to make the new page?

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this by using is_page() or is_home() or is_front_page() to determine homepage, then use  wp_dequeue_style(), wp_enqueue_style(), wp_dequeue_script(), wp_enqueue_script() to remove/add style and js files to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your theme is built you can put if statements in the header to include the appropriate css/js files.

You can do the following -

> ```
>     <?php if(is_front_page()):?> 
>        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/homestyle.css"> 
>        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/homescripts.js"></script> 
>     <?php else: ?> 
>       <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/regularstyle.css">
>       <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/regularscripts.js"></script> 
>    <?php endif;?>
> ```

The slider question is harder to answer without specifics. There are many slider plugins available in the repo that you can add with shortcodes or php codes, but you can also use a regular jQuery slider.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want by creating a new template with a second header as you have described. You mentioned that the only problem you had was with trying to set up the file path, I think you mean calling the new header in your template.  Here's what you do...

1. Copy the homepage template and name it something else (I think you have already done this)
2. Copy the header file and rename it from i.e. `header.php` to `header-home.php`
3. Call the header in your template with `<?php get_header( $header-home ); ?>`
4. Edit the new header-home.php with your new css and js file.

That's it! The home template will now use a custom header.

In regards to the slider as Codebloo has said, there are many free slider plugins available but I recommend Slider Revolution. All you do is install it like any other plugin and you are ready to set up your slides.  When you have created your slides you are given a shortcode or a php insert that you can use on any page, post, or template.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have your template. Next you need to enqueue styles and scripts in your functions.php or wherever you enqueue your assets based on whether you're showing that template or not.

This can easily be done like so:

```
function assets() {
  $assets = array(
    'bootstrap-css' => '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'bootstrap-js'  => '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'css'           => '/assets/css/main.min.css',
    'js'            => '/assets/js/main.min.js',
    'home-css'      => '/different-assets-path/css/main.min.css',
    'home-js'       => '/different-assets-path/js/main.min.js',
  );

  // enqueue common assets here
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', $assets['bootstrap-css'], false, null );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', $assets['bootstrap-js'], array(), null, true );

  if ( is_page_template( 'templates/home.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'home_css', get_template_directory_uri() . $assets['home-css'], false, null );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'home_js', get_template_directory_uri() . $assets['home-js'], array(), null, true );
  } else {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . $assets['css'], false, null );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . $assets['js'], array(), null, true );
  }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'assets', 100 );
```

Regarding adding a slider that's editable from the admin interface. I like to use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to create editable content areas which I then display on the front-end like any other content. This way you're not tied to any particular slider plugin and can change out the javascript and markup to display the slider as you choose.